# Why does Expression Language Interprets dates differently?

Tags: java, el, java.util.date

I have a java bean class that uses java.util.Date for it's date handling.  I know there are better but we are limited and I have to work with what is. 
In a jsp I have the following code:

```
<td>${myBean.sentDate}</td>
<td>${myBean.effDate}</td>
<td>${myBean.disconDate}</td>
```

Now, sentDate is being returned as NULL from the database, and so I create a "LOW DATE" of value "0001-01-01" and parse that using SimpleDateFormat.  I get a java.util.Date with a fastTime of -62135748000000.
diconDate is loaded as the LOW DATE from the database, and the java.util.Date also shows the same fastTime of -62135748000000.

Stepping through the code in Eclipse, i hover over the sentDate and disconDate fields, and I get different displays in the Eclipse window.
sendDate: Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 1
disconDate: 0001-01-01

Lastly, when I view the JSP page via Chrome's debugger, the end result is similarly formatted.

```
<td>Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 1</td>
<td>2020-17-1</td>
<td>0001-01-01</td>
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this?  Is it something I can effect in the creation of the java.util.Date?  Is is something to do with the EL parser?

Comment: What is the exact type of `effDate` and `disconDate`? Is it `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: One is a java.util.Date, one is a java.sql.Date. Their toString() implementation are not the same.

Comment: we are ONLY using java.util.Date...
let me clarify:  in the Bean, we are only referencing java.util.Date.  The process that loads from the database passes a java.sql.Date into the method that is expecting a java.util.Date.  why that isn't type conflict is a whole 'nother discussion.

Comment: java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date.

Comment: Your Question is not at all clear. Please drop the irrelevant detail and variable names. Write some simple code demonstrating your issue, fully documented with explicit definition of your data types and classes involved.

Comment: all relevant information is present. We load the data into a java.util.Date, and when it is sent to the web it is formatted differently, than the the descendent java.sql.Date.  my question is why?  knowing that java.sql.Date descends from java.util.Date may allow me to effect a work around.